# Column index with row-wise maximum value

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
  Newspaper    Month Year          Date      Topic1      Topic2     Topic3      Topic4      Topic5
1  Scotsman December 2005 December 2005 0.013749700 0.000127470 0.38575261 0.000127470 0.070778523
2  Scotsman December 2005 December 2005 0.000165017 0.000165017 0.05219433 0.004611941 0.000165017
3  Scotsman December 2005 December 2005 0.000356507 0.024344932 0.01135670 0.000356507 0.000356507
4  Scotsman December 2005 December 2005 0.000185186 0.000185186 0.10796924 0.044639345 0.106613401
5  Scotsman December 2005 December 2005 0.065869506 0.009775978 0.09610254 0.017584819 0.000103681
6  Scotsman December 2005 December 2005 0.000153257 0.000153257 0.11443001 0.000153257 0.046316677
```

I would like to create a separate variable that corresponds to the `TopicN` with higher percentage.

In the case of the first article (row), it would be 3. Any idea?

Comment: How is your table of data stored at the moment, is it an array, a database ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `max.col()` on the topic columns.  If `df` is the data, try

```
max.col(df[grepl("^Topic", names(df))])
# [1] 3 3 2 3 3 3
```

So to add a new column `MaxPct`, we can do

```
df$MaxPct <- max.col(df[grepl("^Topic", names(df))])
```

Comment: Hey @Richard Scriven, great answer, it should work thanks. I get the following error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable . Any idea why? Cheers!

Comment: Probably because your data is not named `df`?  `df` is also a base R function.  Just plug in the name of your data where you see `df` in my code above.

Comment: What a stupid question, I changed the name of the variable but not the df in the body. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

We can use `apply` with `which.max`

```
unname(apply(df[grepl("^Topic", names(df))], 1, which.max))
#[1] 3 3 2 3 3 3
```