# Add a new column to a dataframe based on results from other columns

Tags: r

I'm very new to R so I hope my question will be interesting. What I want to do is quite straightforward. Here's a sample of my dataset:

```
> head(belongliness)
   ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z   Event  cluster1    cluster2     cluster3    cluster4
1:         40         47         62 Head-up 0.1900989 0.768225365 0.0160654667 0.025610279
2:         60         74         95 Head-up 0.5392218 0.038558310 0.0064671635 0.415752686
3:         62         63         88 Head-up 0.7953673 0.044981152 0.0067121719 0.152939414
4:         60         56         82 Head-up 0.9941016 0.002608879 0.0003007537 0.002988748
5:         66         61         90 Head-up 0.7027407 0.048318016 0.0079239680 0.241017291
6:         60         53         80 Head-up 0.9541378 0.023338896 0.0024442116 0.020079071
```

I would like to create a new column `"winning cluster"` to the right side of column `"cluster 4"`. Column `"winning cluster"` will take the highest value among columns `"cluster 1"` to `"cluster 4"` for each row and display the index name of that column.

For row 1 that will be `cluster 2`, for row 2 `cluster 1`, for row 3 `cluster 1` etc.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try `belongliness[, winning_cluster := do.call(pmax, .SD), .SDcols = paste0("cluster", 1:4)]` (seems like a data.table).  If it is data.frame `belongliness$winng_cluster <- do.call(pmax, belongliness[grep("^cluster", names(belongliness))])`

Comment: I used your first option by writing: `results<-belongliness[, winning_cluster := do.call(pmax, .SD), .SDcols = paste0("cluster", 1:4)]
View(results)` However this will display the highest value for every row, not the name of the column heading the value. I'm I clear?

Comment: YOu want the name of the column, then use `max.col` i.e. `names(bellongliness)[max.col(belongliness[grep("^cluster", names(belongliness))])]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674193/column-index-with-row-wise-maximum-value

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your quick answer. Here's the command I'm running and have the following Error message: `> belongliness[, winning_cluster := do.call(pmax, .SD), .SDcols = paste0("cluster", 1:4)]
> names(belongliness)[max.col(belongliness[grep("^cluster", names(belongliness))])]
[1] NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
In max.col(belongliness[grep("^cluster", names(belongliness))]) :
  NAs introduced by coercion` Any idea about what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Column index with row-wise maximum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674193/column-index-with-row-wise-maximum-value)

Comment: @juansalix. I posted a version that is working fine for me with the example given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dataset is a `data.table` class, specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, get the column index of highest value in each row with `max.col`, use that to select the column name and assign (`:=`) as 'winning_cluster'

```
library(data.table)
belongliness[, winning_cluster := names(.SD)[max.col(.SD)], 
           .SDcols = cluster1:cluster4]
```

Answer (score 1):

In basic R, this is easily done:

```
belongliness$`winning cluster` = apply(belongliness[,5:8], 1, max)
```

where `belongliness[,5:8]` corresponds to columns `cluster1` through `cluster4`.

**Or** if you wanted the index,

```
belongliness$`winning cluster` = apply(belongliness[,5:8], 1, which.max)
belongliness$`winning cluster` = paste0('cluster', belongliness$`winning cluster`)
```

**Edit:** the right hand side of the first line is essentially `max.col`:

```
belongliness$`winning cluster` = max.col(belongliness[,5:8])
```